# How can we redirect light from any direction to one direction?

Tags: optics, refraction

Not just focused light. I mean whenever light come from sideway or any angle. What device it called to refract light from any angle to one angle

Comment: I was just thinking that 'can we take light from all angle and redirect it to one angle" and if this happens I wonder how the part which is not in contact by light will look like, For this to happen first we need to take materials which light can peneterate ( I only know air,liquid and glass tell me if anything else is there) and inside it we need to place something( mirror prob)at an angle where we need to reflect if we do this for every single angle then?
practical it's impossible cause they would stack up on each other *But what if we make a diamond like object all together one which [...]

Comment: [...] reflects light at a single point if we put rays from any angle?

Is there any material which can absolutely absorb light in a small room(not black colour) I mean a thing which lights get attracted to it ? Or anything like bending or solidify

If this exists then we can focus all the light at a single point.And if anything which can bend the light with fabric or absorb & attract light in surroundings Is added to that diamond like object then the surrounding will go black and only the part where light is being directed and the some part of it is visible in short we are eating light

Answer (score 13):

There's no way; it can't be done.

The reason we can be so sure about this is that if this device existed, you could use it to make a perpetual motion machine. Imagine that you have an adiabatic chamber (one that doesn't let any heat in or out), and you place a hot object into the chamber. This object will give off thermal radiation until the adiabatic box is filled with radiation at the same temperature as the object. This radiation will be the same in all directions, as it's made of photons bouncing around the box and being emitted and absorbed at random. At this point the system is in equilibrium - you shouldn't be able to extract any work from it.

But if you now put your device into the box, it will take in the radiation (i.e. light) from all angles and concentrate it in one direction. This means that one part of the box will get hotter than the rest, since it's now absorbing more photons. And since you have a hotter and a colder region, you can put a heat engine into the box as well, and extract work. Once you've used this work it will turn back into heat, and if this also takes place inside the box then this heat can be turned back into work again, and the system can run forever.

But since we know perpetual motion machines are impossible, we know that this situation must be impossible, and that tells us your device can't exist. The second law of thermodynamics puts some quite strong constraints on what you can do with optics, and this is one of them.

Comment: I'm doubtful about this sentence: "Once you've used this work and turned it into heat, you can put the heat back into the box and turn it into work again, forever." That last word in particular bugs me. You won't have a 100% efficient heat engine, so even if you can get the rest of the setup to work, this shouldn't be a perpetual motion machine, right? I'm thinking non-linear optics by the way, I'd say you could get a fair amount of randomly oriented light redirected using higher order effects, which can be made highly directional. They definitely won't be 100% efficient either, though.

Comment: Well, if the heat engine is inefficient all it will do is put out a little more heat, which will still be in the box and can still be turned into work eventually. As long as no energy leaves the box, it could run forever.

Comment: @Nathaniel All you've shown is that your device must start to fail as it heats up or cools down beyond its designed operating range. The fallacious part is your use of the word forever. I could use the same argument as you gave to show that ice can't exist becausu if I threw ice into a warm already-in-equilibrium adiabatic chamber there would be a temperature gradient and then I can add the word forever (as if equilibrium taking forever to achieve means you have a PMM). Similar reasoning would show superconductors can't exist. They can, but they need to be cooled to operate in some conditions.

Comment: Nathaniel's analysis is correct (and the idea of putting the lens into a cavity is excellent), but his idea of building a perpetual motion machine is not. Any work done by the system will result in energy leaving the system; it will stop when the box reaches absolute zero. The underlying problem does not relate to heat so much as entropy; Nathaniels thought experiment shows that if such a lens existed it could be used to create a closed system which reduces its own entropy. That's not possible.

Comment: @PeterWebb You're correct that it's about violating the 2nd law by decreasing entropy in a closed system. Nathaniel closed his system by stating the box was a perfect insulator, an "*adiabatic chamber (one that doesn't let any heat in or out)*". No energy will leave the system.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably looking for is a tube lens, or infinity-corrected tube lens. It takes all light from a point source that fit into lens aperture, and transforms it into parallel bundle of rays.

You can take a look on [Throlabs page](http://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5834) for more information and actual products, or [Nikon's](http://www.microscopyu.com/articles/optics/cfintro.html) (not an ad!).

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I watched a video on YouTube, candle lights reaction to centrifugal motion, the light of the candle works more like a magnet, always leaning toward the center actuator. Working against gravity. If left still,  the candle light may illuminate its surroundings equally, but once set in motion, the candle light defies gravity, acting more like a compass, always directing the flame tip towards the center of your centrifugal device. In theory, if you set multiple lights onto your platform you could focus the lights physical state in another direction by setting it in motion

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/393322)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'm no physicists so please excuse my accent. The charge of a particle going from higher charge to a lower charge, they say that process creates a light of some sort. If you could some how create a point of contact. Eye to eye in a sense to interact with the light to create a synergy of some sort you could possibly manipulate the amount of light focused in that aim of sight

Comment: A link, or point of contact in the direction desired would be necessary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/393325)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that's related to what you want. I don't have much to say about it.

[Light traps](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.6955&rep=rep1&type=pdf)